# Why does Android 6.0+ require RECORD_AUDIO permission in order to send Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG

Tags: android, android-intent, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I have a BroadcastReceiver that I construct and register at runtime to receive `Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG` so that I get notified whenever the headset is plugged or unplugged.

Prior to Android 6.0 this worked perfectly, but since then I only receive the Intent if `RECORD_AUDIO` permission has been granted.

I had wanted to use notification of that Intent to ask the user for the RECORD_AUDIO permission, but now I have no good point at which to do so. So I'll have to ask for permission on start up regardless of whether they are interested in audio or not.

I can't see why the app would require `RECORD_AUDIO` just to know whether you had plugged in your headphones.

Is there a way to receive `ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG` without requiring `RECORD_AUDIO` in Android 6.0+ and targeting Android 23+?

NB the system does recognise that a headset has been plugged in (system log shown below), but `ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG` is not sent to my app unless it has been granted `RECORD_AUDIO`.

```
06-13 22:18:21.176 5509-7053/? V/WiredAccessoryManager: notifyWiredAccessoryChanged: when=24261279475000 bits=SW_HEADPHONE_INSERT SW_MICROPHONE_INSERT mask=94
06-13 22:18:21.177 5509-7053/? V/WiredAccessoryManager: newName=h2w newState=1 headsetState=1 prev headsetState=0
06-13 22:18:21.177 5509-7053/? I/WiredAccessoryManager: MSG_NEW_DEVICE_STATE
06-13 22:18:21.178 5509-5509/? V/WiredAccessoryManager: headsetName:  connected
06-13 22:18:21.205 4345-4345/? I/AudioFlinger: openOutput(), module 10 Device 4, SamplingRate 8000, Format 0x1000000, Channels 1, flags 31
06-13 22:18:21.206 4345-4345/? I/AudioFlinger: HAL output buffer size 262144 frames, normal sink buffer size 262144 frames
06-13 22:18:21.215 4345-26896/? I/AudioFlinger: AudioFlinger's thread 0xe94fc000 ready to run
06-13 22:18:21.227 4345-26896/? D/audio_hw_primary: out_set_parameters: enter: usecase(3: compress-offload-playback) kvpairs: closing=true
06-13 22:18:21.227 4345-4345/? D/audio_hw_primary: out_set_parameters: enter: usecase(3: compress-offload-playback) kvpairs: exiting=1
06-13 22:18:21.229 4345-26892/? E/audio_hw_primary: offload_thread_loop: Compress handle is NULL
06-13 22:18:21.230 4345-4696/? D/audio_hw_primary: out_set_parameters: enter: usecase(1: low-latency-playback) kvpairs: routing=0
06-13 22:18:21.237 4345-26897/? I/AudioFlinger: AudioFlinger's thread 0xe6e039c0 ready to run
06-13 22:18:21.239 4345-26898/? I/AudioFlinger: AudioFlinger's thread 0xe6d83dc0 ready to run
06-13 22:18:21.248 8921-8921/? V/MediaRouter: Updating audio routes: AudioRoutesInfo{ type=HEADSET }
06-13 22:18:21.248 8921-8921/? V/MediaRouter: Dispatching route change: RouteInfo{ name=Headphones, description=null, status=null, category=RouteCategory{ name=null types=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO  groupable=false }, supportedTypes=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO , presentationDisplay=null }
06-13 22:18:21.250 25097-25097/? V/MediaRouter: Updating audio routes: AudioRoutesInfo{ type=HEADSET }
06-13 22:18:21.251 25097-25097/? V/MediaRouter: Dispatching route change: RouteInfo{ name=Headphones, description=null, status=null, category=RouteCategory{ name=null types=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO  groupable=false }, supportedTypes=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO , presentationDisplay=null }
06-13 22:18:21.253 5509-5509/? V/MediaRouter: Updating audio routes: AudioRoutesInfo{ type=HEADSET }
06-13 22:18:21.253 5509-5509/? V/MediaRouter: Dispatching route change: RouteInfo{ name=Headphones, description=null, status=null, category=RouteCategory{ name=null types=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO  groupable=false }, supportedTypes=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO , presentationDisplay=null }
06-13 22:18:21.274 7274-7335/? I/vol.Events: writeEvent level_changed STREAM_VOICE_CALL 5
06-13 22:18:21.275 7274-7335/? I/vol.Events: writeEvent level_changed STREAM_SYSTEM 7
06-13 22:18:21.282 7274-7274/? V/MediaRouter: Updating audio routes: AudioRoutesInfo{ type=HEADSET }
06-13 22:18:21.282 7274-7274/? V/MediaRouter: Dispatching route change: RouteInfo{ name=Headphones, description=null, status=null, category=RouteCategory{ name=null types=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO  groupable=false }, supportedTypes=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO , presentationDisplay=null }
06-13 22:18:21.300 5509-5509/? I/Telecom: WiredHeadsetManager: ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG event, plugged in: true, : WHC.oADA@A60
06-13 22:18:21.302 5509-7538/? I/Telecom: CallAudioRouteStateMachine: Message received: CONNECT_WIRED_HEADSET=1, arg1=0: WHC.oADA->CARSM.pM_CONNECT_WIRED_HEADSET@A60_0
06-13 22:18:21.303 5509-7538/? I/Telecom: Telecom: Non-call EVENT: AUDIO_ROUTE, Wired headset connected: WHC.oADA->CARSM.pM_CONNECT_WIRED_HEADSET@A60_0
06-13 22:18:21.303 5509-7538/? I/Telecom: CallAudioRouteStateMachine: Message received: SWITCH_HEADSET=1003, arg1=0: WHC.oADA->CARSM.pM_CONNECT_WIRED_HEADSET->CARSM.pM_SWITCH_HEADSET@A60_0_0
06-13 22:18:21.303 5509-7538/? I/Telecom: Telecom: Non-call EVENT: AUDIO_ROUTE, Leaving state QuiescentEarpieceRoute: WHC.oADA->CARSM.pM_CONNECT_WIRED_HEADSET->CARSM.pM_SWITCH_HEADSET@A60_0_0
06-13 22:18:21.303 5509-7538/? I/Telecom: Telecom: Non-call EVENT: AUDIO_ROUTE, Entering state QuiescentHeadsetRoute: WHC.oADA->CARSM.pM_CONNECT_WIRED_HEADSET->CARSM.pM_SWITCH_HEADSET@A60_0_0
```

Comment: no u cant  cause its under the user permission.
other wise u can use  below 23 api

Comment: Does anything show up in LogCat when you plug/unplug the headset, with your receiver (sans permission) registered?

Comment: Good thinking @CommonsWare. Added it above.

Comment: Interesting. I had expected to see a message saying that the broadcast could not be sent to your receiver because you lack the `RECORD_AUDIO` permission. I think `RECORD_AUDIO` is sticky, which might explain (a teeny bit) why this permission is required. You used to be able to simulate headset events via `adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG`, but that's now a protected broadcast, so we can't use that to debug. I haven't played with `ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG` in ages. Is there some listener on `AudioManager` that you can use instead?

Comment: Thanks. Looks like AudioManager.registerAudioDeviceCallback() might be fit for purpose.